# kmeans.cluster() giving error "TypeError: 'float' object is not iterable" on using wordembedding (word2vec) for sentences

Tags: python, k-means, word2vec

I am trying to cluster sentences using kmeans 
but am not getting the input type right for `cluster()`.

I have tried using list Y with `wordembedding` created using `sent_vectorizer` def and have also tried the `dataframe` version of Y.

```
def sent_vectorizer(sent, model): #creates vectors for each tokenized sentence
    sent_vec =[]
    numw = 0
    for w in sent:
        try:
            if numw == 0:
                sent_vec = model[w]
            else:
                sent_vec = np.add(sent_vec, model[w]) #adds vectors of all words in a sentence over iterations
            numw+=1 #counts the number of words in all sentences
        except:
            pass

    return np.asarray(sent_vec) / numw

Y=[]
for sentence in all_words:
    Y.append(sent_vectorizer(sentence, model))   

print ("========================")
print (Y)

df_Y = pd.DataFrame(Y) 

NUM_CLUSTERS=3
kclusterer = KMeansClusterer(NUM_CLUSTERS, distance=nltk.cluster.util.cosine_distance, repeats=25,avoid_empty_clusters=True)
assigned_clusters = kclusterer.cluster(df_Y, assign_clusters=True)
print (assigned_clusters)
```

all_words has a list of tokenized sentences:

`[['cloud', 'technologies'], ['still', 'building', 'strong', 'foundation', 'game', 'changers', 'hyper', 'converged', 'technology', 'sd', 'wan', 'tying', 'colleges', 'together', 'one', 'seamless', 'security', 'plane', 'protecting', 'college', 'data'], ['none'], ['data', 'analytics'], ['customer', 'experience', 'improvements'], ['ar', 'vr'], ['none', 'timeframe', 'longer', 'term', 'cloud', 'services', 'ai', 'technologies', 'game', 'changer'], ['cloud', 'finance', 'integrated', 'ship', 'management'], ['microservices', 'based', 'api', 'platform', 'omni', 'channels'], ['moving', 'erp', 'cloud'], ['online', 'learning', 'open', 'educational', 'resources'], ['online', 'programs', 'meet', 'needs', 'today', 'learners'], ['automation', 'existing', 'processes']]`

error traceback:

````
    ---------------------------------------------------------------------------
    TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
    <ipython-input-108-68f5fe386b54> in <module>
          1 NUM_CLUSTERS=3
          2 kclusterer = KMeansClusterer(NUM_CLUSTERS, distance=nltk.cluster.util.cosine_distance, repeats=25,avoid_empty_clusters=True)
    ----> 3 assigned_clusters = kclusterer.cluster(df_Y, assign_clusters=True)
          4 print (assigned_clusters)

    ~\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\nltk\cluster\util.py in cluster(self, vectors, assign_clusters, trace)
         60 
         61         # call abstract method to cluster the vectors
    ---> 62         self.cluster_vectorspace(vectors, trace)
         63 
         64         # assign the vectors to clusters

    ~\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\nltk\cluster\kmeans.py in cluster_vectorspace(self, vectors, trace)
         99             # effect the distance comparison)
        100             for means in meanss:
    --> 101                 means.sort(key=sum)
        102 
        103             # find the set of means that's minimally different from the others

    TypeError: 'float' object is not iterable ```

I also tried the following code and get error there as well:
    ```
    kmeans = cluster.KMeans(n_clusters=NUM_CLUSTERS)
    kmeans.fit(Y)
    ```
the error in this case is:
    ```
    ---------------------------------------------------------------------------
    ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
    <ipython-input-48-229383cd99be> in <module>
          1 kmeans = cluster.KMeans(n_clusters=NUM_CLUSTERS)
    ----> 2 kmeans.fit(Y)
          3 
          4 labels = kmeans.labels_
          5 centroids = kmeans.cluster_centers_

    ~\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\sklearn\cluster\k_means_.py in fit(self, X, y, sample_weight)
        969                 tol=self.tol, random_state=random_state, copy_x=self.copy_x,
        970                 n_jobs=self.n_jobs, algorithm=self.algorithm,
    --> 971                 return_n_iter=True)
        972         return self
        973 

    ~\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\sklearn\cluster\k_means_.py in k_means(X, n_clusters, sample_weight, init, precompute_distances, n_init, max_iter, verbose, tol, random_state, copy_x, n_jobs, algorithm, return_n_iter)
        309     order = "C" if copy_x else None
        310     X = check_array(X, accept_sparse='csr', dtype=[np.float64, np.float32],
    --> 311                     order=order, copy=copy_x)
        312     # verify that the number of samples given is larger than k
        313     if _num_samples(X) < n_clusters:

    ~\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\sklearn\utils\validation.py in check_array(array, accept_sparse, accept_large_sparse, dtype, order, copy, force_all_finite, ensure_2d, allow_nd, ensure_min_samples, ensure_min_features, warn_on_dtype, estimator)
        525             try:
        526                 warnings.simplefilter('error', ComplexWarning)
    --> 527                 array = np.asarray(array, dtype=dtype, order=order)
        528             except ComplexWarning:
        529                 raise ValueError("Complex data not supported\n"

    ~\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\numpy\core\numeric.py in asarray(a, dtype, order)
        536 
        537     """
    --> 538     return array(a, dtype, copy=False, order=order)
        539 
        540 

    ValueError: setting an array element with a sequence.
````

Comment: Can you post the traceback of error

Comment: Check the type of `sent`. And add complete traceback as well to the question by using the edit option.

Comment: type(sent) is str and I have added tracebacks for both the codes tried